# how to query a specific record from solr?

Tags: laravel, solr

this is how data looks like.

```
id = 54,
name = john,
date_of_birth = 02-02-02
```

and

```
id = 55,
name = julie
```

when no filter applied, only those records which don't have date_of_birth field should be shown but if the user wants to check which record has the date_of_birth field, then only those records which have date_of_birth field, are shown. how can we achieve this with solr?

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select records that doesn't have a field present by querying for `*:* -date_of_birth:[* TO *]`, and you can query for all documents that have a specific field by querying for `date_of_birth:[* TO *]`.

If you look at these queries you may see how they're related:

```
date_of_birth:[* TO *]
```

.. results in a list of documents that have the field present. In the other (first) query, we use that same query, but now we subtract it as a negative query instead - meaning that any documents that match it will be removed from the set of documents in front of it. The special query `*:*` means "all documents in the index".

```
*:* -date_of_birth:[* TO *]
```

If this is the only part of your query, you can usually drop the `*:*` part, as it'll be added automagically by Solr in front of your query if the query is purely negative. However, if it one part of a larger query, prepending `*:*` yourself will be necessary.